# Use javascript to show data from sql as it is Typed in HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a SQL database page to store data but I'm stuck at displaying data from sql as it is typed.

Heres what html form looks like

[image]

Now in above image, the 'Model Group' and 'Model Varient' Fields are readonly. Now I want to fill the two forms as soon as I type the VIN number.
The typed vin number is already stored in sql database. Can anyone suggest what code should I use or some reference Documents? Google serach didn't help much with this one.
Incase you need, the sql database looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to send the typed VIN to a back-end App, so it can get the data for the VIN from the DB. To do this from your web page, you're going to want to make an AJAX call to the server App, then parse the response when it comes back. So, I'd search for how to implement AJAX calls - there should be plenty of info out there (start with w3schools.com).

Answer (score 0):

**If you want user to write the input:**

First thing to do is to `select` all `vin` values and store them as input for HTML `data-list` tag.

Then you can use the code below (instead of input tag that you are using now):

```
<input list="vinData" name="vinValue" required>
  <datalist id="vinData">
    <option value="89841321">
    <option value="546123">
    <option value="213134984">
  </datalist>
```

You should make `option` using PHP with a loop

---

Or you can just simply use html `select` tag. **This way user can't write anything and has to choose one of the options.**

```
<select>
  <option value="89841321">89841321</option>
  <option value="546123">546123</option>
  <option value="213134984">213134984</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do perform ajax request on blur event of vinno.

```
$('body').on('.vin-no','blur', function(){
   $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        url: 'server.php',
        data: {vinno: $(this).val()}
        success: function(response){
            $('.model-group').val(response.modelgroup);
            $('.model-variant').val(response.modelvariant);
        }
   });
})
```

Also as @ali said it need to be an select list so user can select one of existing value. If you use 'select' you can make the 'blur' event to 'change' event.
I have used jquery ajax calls and ajax request need to be performed on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

As @RobertFrenette wrote (and if I undestand what you try to achieve) it will require multiple communications scripts between front html - via AJAX to PHP - from PHP to SQL - and all back to user-end html form. Try this approach

#### 1 Call ajax to send user input (vin number)

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="vin-input">
<input type="text" id="model-group" disabled>
<input type="text" id="model-varient" disabled>


enter code here
```

Javascript (with jQuery) code:

```
//When only user change VIN number call this function.
$("#vin-input").keyup(function( event ){
  var input = $(this).val();

  //Regex validate to prevent AJAX request when not needed.
  //@todo change regex to your VIN schema.
  var properInput = new RegExp('^[0-9]{6,}$');
  if (properInput.test(input)) {
            
    //@todo remove this
    alert(input + " ok - send ajax");
    //Send AJAX to PHP script.
    //@todo change "get-vin.php" to your PHP script name.
    $.post( "get-vin-data.php", {"vin": input})
      .done( function( data ) {
        //Handle data returning from PHP script.
        //@todo parse returning data and put it into form.
        $( "#model-group" ).val( "model 45" );
        $( "#model-varient" ).val( "varient 45" );
      })
      .fail(function() {
        //Handle failure of AJAX call (here it will always fail).
        $( "#model-group" ).val( "model 45" );
        $( "#model-varient" ).val( "varient 45" );
      });
  }
})
```

You can see regex matching as you should try to improve performance and validate vin number to call AJAX only when it is needed. You should **change regex** to fit your VIN schema.

[Front end fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/any60kbm/1/)

#### 2 Get data in backend and return to your script

This part I must leave to you. You have to:

- create script (in my example it is named `get-vin-data.php` but you can name it as you wish and in any technology you use.
- It should return information to your user-end script - small and simple as possible eg. JSON `{model-group: "group 32", model-varient: "reddish"}`.
- Append this data to proper inputs in HTML - in JS example its code part `//@todo parse returning data and put it into form.`.

Good luck.